# IronPython use C# module documentation

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a C# module which can be imported into IronPython (well, technically the all can, but one that's meant to be imported). However, the default help used for C# modules by IronPython just isn't sufficient enough.

Is there a way to grab and attach the VS exported xml documentation to a C# module with IronPython's help system? Or is there some way in the C# code to specify what IronPython should put in lieu of the default documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XML file is in the same location as the assembly and has the same filename just with ".xml" instead of ".exe" or ".dll" then IronPython should pick it up and include it in relevant doc strings for types, methods, etc...

Comment: thanks, is there a way I could also IronPython to pickup the help docs from "built-in" .net functions/fields/classes/etc.?

Comment: That should happen automatically if you have the XML documentation installed but it requires the user has the reference assemblies installed (which brings along the documentation).  I'm not sure how to install just the reference assemblies but the place they get installed/we look is %ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0